# How to Download Sales Order Invoice from Odoo 15 Using XML-RPC or JSON-RPC in Python Flask Without SSH Access?

Tags: python, odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-15, odoo-17

I'm working on a Python Flask application where I need to download sales order invoices from Odoo 15 using either XML-RPC or JSON-RPC. However, due to security constraints, I cannot access the Odoo source code via SSH. The only data I have is the Odoo database name, username, password, and the ID of the invoice I want to download.

Is there a way to call an API or utilize XML-RPC/JSON-RPC methods to download the sales order invoice directly from Odoo 15 without accessing the source code? Any code snippets or guidance on how to achieve this within a Python Flask environment would be greatly appreciated.

```py
import xmlrpc.client
import json
import base64
from urllib.request import urlopen
from flask import Flask, request, send_file

# Odoo Configuration 
url = 'https://your_odoo_instance_url.com'
db = 'your_odoo_database'
username = 'your_odoo_username'
password = 'your_odoo_password'

# Core Invoice Fetching Logic
def fetch_and_download_invoice_xmlrpc(invoice_id):
    """Fetches and downloads a sales invoice using XML-RPC"""
    common = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))
    uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})
    models = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))

    # Fetch the PDF content 
    pdf_content_encoded = models.execute_kw(
        db, uid, password, 'ir.actions.report', 'render_qweb_pdf_inherit', [invoice_id]
    )
    pdf_data = base64.b64decode(pdf_content_encoded)

    with open('invoice_{}.pdf'.format(invoice_id), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(pdf_data)

def fetch_and_download_invoice_jsonrpc(invoice_id):
    """Fetches and downloads a sales invoice using JSON-RPC"""
    aurl = f"{url}/jsonrpc"
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

    # Authentication
    auth_data = {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "call",
        "params": {"db": db, "login": username, "password": password},
        "id": 1
    }
    auth_response = json.loads(urlopen(aurl, json.dumps(auth_data).encode()).read())
    if auth_response.get('error'):
        raise Exception(auth_response['error'])
    uid = auth_response['result']

    # Fetch and download invoice
    data = {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "call",
        "params": {
            "service": "object",
            "method": "execute",
            "args": [db, uid, password, 'ir.actions.report', 'render_qweb_pdf', [invoice_id]]
        },
        "id": 2
    }
    pdf_response = json.loads(urlopen(aurl, json.dumps(data).encode()).read())
    pdf_data = base64.b64decode(pdf_response['result'])

    with open('invoice_{}.pdf'.format(invoice_id), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(pdf_data)

# Flask Application
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/download_invoice', methods=['GET'])
def download_invoice():
    invoice_id = request.args.get('invoice_id')
    if not invoice_id:
        return "Please provide an invoice ID", 400

    try:
        # Choose either XML-RPC or JSON-RPC
        fetch_and_download_invoice_xmlrpc(int(invoice_id))  # Convert to integer
        fetch_and_download_invoice_jsonrpc(int(invoice_id))

        return send_file('invoice_{}.pdf'.format(invoice_id), as_attachment=True)

    except Exception as e:
        return str(e), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is how I tried with both XML-RPC and JSON-RPC

**Edit**
I've got the answer and this below code works

```py
# Import necessary modules from Flask framework and other libraries
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, send_file
import xmlrpc.client
import requests

# Set up credentials and URL for Odoo instance
url = 'https://your_odoo_instance_url.com'
db = 'your_odoo_database'
username = 'your_odoo_username'
password = 'your_odoo_password'

# Authenticate and get session ID from Odoo
session_url = f'{url}web/session/authenticate'
data = {
    'jsonrpc': '2.0',
    'method': 'call',
    'params': {
        "service": "common",
        "method": "login",
        'db': db,
        'login': username,
        'password': password,
    }
}
session_response = requests.post(session_url, json=data)
session_data = session_response.json()
session_id = session_response.cookies['session_id']

# Set up XML-RPC connection to Odoo
common = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))
uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})
models = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))

# Specify the ID of the invoice to retrieve
invoice_id = 21566

# Retrieve information about the specified invoice from Odoo
invoice = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'account.move', 'read', [invoice_id], {'fields': ['name']})

# Trigger the action to send and print the invoice, and retrieve the URL of the generated PDF
pdf_file_url = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'account.move.send', 'action_send_and_print', [4, [invoice_id]])

# Set up headers with the session ID for downloading the PDF
headers = {'Cookie': f'session_id={session_id}'}
download_url = f'{url}{pdf_file_url["url"]}'

# Download the PDF content of the invoice
response = requests.get(download_url, headers=headers)
pdf_content = response.content

# Specify the filename for the downloaded PDF based on the invoice name
filename = '{}.pdf'.format(invoice[0]['name'])

# Save the PDF content to a file
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(pdf_content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the below code and let me know if it helps:

```
import xmlrpc.client
import json
import base64
from urllib.request import urlopen
from flask import Flask, request, send_file

# Odoo Configuration
url = 'https://your_odoo_instance_url.com'
db = 'your_odoo_database'
username = 'your_odoo_username'
password = 'your_odoo_password'

# Core Invoice Fetching Logic
def fetch_and_download_invoice(invoice_id, rpc_method):
    """Fetches and downloads a sales invoice using the specified RPC method"""
    if rpc_method not in ['xmlrpc', 'jsonrpc']:
        raise ValueError("Invalid RPC method")

    if rpc_method == 'xmlrpc':
        common = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))
        uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})
        models = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))
    else:  # jsonrpc
        aurl = f"{url}/jsonrpc"
        auth_data = {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "call", "params": {"db": db, "login": username, "password": password}, "id": 1}
        auth_response = json.loads(urlopen(aurl, json.dumps(auth_data).encode()).read())
        if auth_response.get('error'):
            raise Exception(auth_response['error'])
        uid = auth_response['result']

    # Fetch and download invoice
    data = {"jsonrpc": "2.0" if rpc_method == 'jsonrpc' else None,
            "method": "call",
            "params": {"service": "object", "method": "execute", "args": [db, uid, password, 'ir.actions.report', 'render_qweb_pdf', [invoice_id]]},
            "id": 2 if rpc_method == 'jsonrpc' else None}
    pdf_response = json.loads(urlopen(aurl, json.dumps(data).encode()).read()) if rpc_method == 'jsonrpc' else models.execute_kw(
        db, uid, password, 'ir.actions.report', 'render_qweb_pdf_inherit', [invoice_id]
    )
    pdf_data = base64.b64decode(pdf_response['result'] if rpc_method == 'jsonrpc' else pdf_response)

    with open(f'invoice_{invoice_id}.pdf', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(pdf_data)

# Flask Application
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/download_invoice', methods=['GET'])
def download_invoice():
    invoice_id = request.args.get('invoice_id')
    rpc_method = request.args.get('rpc_method', 'jsonrpc')  # Default to JSON-RPC if not specified
    if not invoice_id:
        return "Please provide an invoice ID", 400

    try:
        fetch_and_download_invoice(int(invoice_id), rpc_method)
        return send_file(f'invoice_{invoice_id}.pdf', as_attachment=True)

    except Exception as e:
        return str(e), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This code consolidates the logic for both XML-RPC and JSON-RPC into a single `fetch_and_download_invoice` function, which allows you to choose the RPC method dynamically based on the `rpc_method` parameter.

Comment: I'm getting the following error when I'm passing 'xmlrpc' to the params
`<Faultraise AttributeError(f"The method \'
    {name}\' does not exist on the model \'{model._name}\'")\nAttributeError: The method \'render_qweb_pdf_inherit\'
    does not exist on the model \'ir.actions.report\'\n'>`

Comment: When I'm using 'jsonrpc' then I'm getting

`HTTP Error 400: BAD REQUEST`